# Saiku query fetch

Tags: backbone.js, highcharts, pentaho, drilldown, saiku

I'm new to saiku and backbone. I'm trying to figure out how ChartPlus highcharts work in Saiku and have integrated Saiku in Pentaho. I have downloaded the source code, been going through the code and trying to figure out how the database is being hit to generate the charts. I found the below event for fetching the query but unable to find where it is defined and how it is getting called.

```
   this.workspace.trigger('query:fetch');
```

Can anyone help out by telling how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Saiku CE and Saiku Chart Plus using Pentaho Marketplace or you can build the Saiku source and put in folder in **pentaho-solutions** and restart server.

The code that you spoke, you can see the event created here: https://github.com/OSBI/saiku/blob/master/saiku-ui/js/saiku/models/Query.js#L135

> Trigger callbacks for the given event, or space-delimited list of
>   events. Subsequent arguments to trigger will be passed along to the
>   event callbacks.

You could catch it using:

```
var MyClass = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(args) {
    // Keep track of parent workspace
    this.workspace = args.workspace;

    // Maintain `this` in callbacks
    _.bindAll(this, 'receive_data', 'workspace_levels');

    // Listen to result event
    this.workspace.bind('query:fetch', this.receive_data);
  },

  receive_data: function(args) {
    console.log(args);
  },
});
```